# How to convert a text string in an input function into an integer?

Tags: python, input, integer

I am trying to write a very simple programme for a rock, paper, scissors game. I produce a random integer which is the opponent's move, and then I input my own "guess" in integer form. Then, I combine these two integers into a list and test these coordinates against a results matrix.

I have converted "rock", "paper" and "scissors" into integers as follows:

```
    guess = input("Enter your move: \"rock\", \"paper\", \"scissors\", or \"quit\": \n")
    if guess == "rock":
        guess = 0
    if guess == "paper":
        guess = 1
    if guess == "scissors":
        guess = 2
    if guess == "quit":
        break
    weapon = random.randint(0, 2)  # 0 is rock, 1 is paper, 2 is scissors
    outputGuess = (int(guess), int(weapon))
```

Is there a way to get rid of all the if statements? I have tried the following, but it does not work:

```
    guess = input("Enter your move: \"rock\", \"paper\", \"scissors\", or \"quit\": \n")
    "rock" = 0
    "paper" = 1
    "scissors" = 2
    weapon = random.randint(0, 2)  # 0 is rock, 1 is paper, 2 is scissors
    outputGuess = (int(guess), int(weapon))
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can try using Enums and then parse it back in the comparisons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a dict to translate it into its integer counterpart.

```
guess = input("Enter your move: \"rock\", \"paper\", \"scissors\", or \"quit\": \n")

guesses = {'rock':0, 'paper':1, 'scissors':2}
weapon = random.randint(0, 2)
output = (guesses[guess], weapon)
```

You don't need to change the type of the weapon since it is already an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use 1 line `if statement`. The syntax is `result if condition else result`.

```py
guess = 0 if guess=='rock' else 1 if guess=='paper' else 2 if guess=='scissors' else break
```

It checks if it's `rock`, otherwise check if its `paper`, otherwise check if its `scissors`, otherwise `break` because it's none of the guess

Answer (score 1):

There are already two great answers that would solve the problem but here is my solution. You can put the strings into a list called `options` and then get the index of the `guess`.

```py
guess = input("Enter your move: \"rock\", \"paper\", \"scissors\", or \"quit\": \n")
options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
if guess in options:
    guess = options.index(guess)
else:
    break

weapon = random.randint(0, 2)  # 0 is rock, 1 is paper, 2 is scissors
outputGuess = (guess, weapon)
```

I removed the `int()` in the `outputGuess` line because the `randint()` and `index()` functions both return an integer.

Answer (score 1):

As @SharathNS suggested, you can try exploring the usage of enums so that everything is defined in 1 place where you would have greater control over the possible options.

```
from enum import Enum
import random


class GameOption(Enum):
    rock = 0
    paper = 1
    scissors = 2

GAME_OPTION_KEYS = [option.name for option in GameOption]
GAME_OPTION_VALUES = [option.value for option in GameOption]

while (guess := input(f"Enter your move: {GAME_OPTION_KEYS}, or \"quit\": \n")) != "quit":
    weapon = random.choice(GAME_OPTION_VALUES)
    outputGuess = (GameOption[guess], "vs", GameOption(weapon))
    print(outputGuess)
```

Output

```
$ python3 script.py 
Enter your move: ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'], or "quit": 
paper
(<GameOption.paper: 1>, 'vs', <GameOption.scissors: 2>)
Enter your move: ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'], or "quit": 
paper
(<GameOption.paper: 1>, 'vs', <GameOption.paper: 1>)
Enter your move: ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'], or "quit": 
rock
(<GameOption.rock: 0>, 'vs', <GameOption.scissors: 2>)
Enter your move: ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'], or "quit": 
scissors
(<GameOption.scissors: 2>, 'vs', <GameOption.rock: 0>)
Enter your move: ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'], or "quit": 
rock
(<GameOption.rock: 0>, 'vs', <GameOption.paper: 1>)
Enter your move: ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'], or "quit": 
quit
```